# Why does my cat yowl to go meet the tomcat?

Tags: cats

I have a 4 year old neutered female cat, the past few nights she has started screaming and yowling all night when locked inside. Tonight she woke me up 4 times, and when I went to turn on the light outside, a local tom cat was standing at the back door.

I let my dog out to scare the tomcat but my cat still wouldn't stop yowling, so I let her outside. Once outside, she continued yowling until she found the tom. Once together they ran up the street, my cat very low to the ground as if stalking him while the other cat had a relaxed posture. I thought maybe she was scaring him off however they were just facing each other normally, with no issues. What is going on? Why is my cat yowling and why does she want to meet up with this other cat?

Comment: Are you 100% certain she has been fully neutered? This sounds a lot like what female cats are like in heat, in other words mating behaviour.

Comment: Issues start when the yowling *stops*. That's not what you want the situation to escalate to, but you're also not supposed to interfere. It doesn't matter if they're neutered or not, this is a territorial dispute.

Answer (score 2):

It does sound somewhat similar to mating behavior, was she neutered "late"? Sometimes cats that have been fixed *after* already reaching sexual maturity can still act out the behaviors even though nothing can actually come of it so it could be that.